# Scala Template unable to tokenise an HTML attribute?

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-template

I'd like a Scala condition inside the "class" HTML attribute to be parsed, but the Scala Template isn't playing ball:

```
@priceTag(amount: Currency) = @{
    <div class='priceTag {if(amount.toDouble == 0.0d) "FREE"}'>
        {if(amount.toDouble > 0.0d) {amount.format("¤#")} else {"FREE"}}
    </div>
}
```

Yields:

```
<div class="priceTag {if(amount.toDouble == 0.0d) &quot;FREE&quot;}"> 
    £1
</div>
```

And I'd like it to yield:

```
<div class="priceTag"> 
    £1
</div>
```

Suggestions gratefully appreciated

Comment: It looks like you're missing some `@` signs (`@{if...}`). I'm surprised the content of the div is `£1` instead of the whole `if` line.

Comment: @Carsten thanks for the reply, but unfortunately adding the @ sign there doesn't help. Yields HTML: class="priceTag @{if(amount.toDouble == 0.0d) "FREE"}"

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't see the second `@` sign in the first line. *writing an answer*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several errors. They just hide each other. :-)

Let's go through them:

```
@priceTag(amount: Currency) = @{ ... }
```

The `@{ ... }` construct means that everything inside the curly brackets is a block of Scala code. This doesn't rause an error, because your block,

```
<div class='priceTag {if(amount.toDouble == 0.0d) "FREE"}'>
    {if(amount.toDouble > 0.0d) {amount.format("¤#")} else {"FREE"}}
</div>
```

is actually valid Scala code (because of Scala's XML literals). It's just that Scala recognizes `priceTag {if(amount.toDouble == 0.0d) "FREE"}` as the class name of your `div`.

What you probably wanted to do is this:

```
@priceTag(amount: Currency) = {
    <div class='priceTag @{if(amount.toDouble == 0.0d) "FREE"}'>
        @{if(amount.toDouble > 0.0d) amount.format("¤#") else "FREE"}
    </div>
}
```

Notice the `@` signs before the two `if` blocks. I have also removed the curly brackets around `amount.format("¤#")` and `"FREE"`. You can keep them of course, if you want, but they're not required.

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner in scala but the if statement is not correct to me, I would go with:

```
@if(amount > 0) {
        <div class="priceTag"> 
           @amount
        </div>
} else {
        <div class="priceTag FREE"> 
           @amount
        </div>
}
```

Or:

```
        <div class="priceTag @if(amount == 0) { FREE }"> 
           @amount
        </div>
```